# DriveApp create a folder in Standard GCP, not run

Tags: google-apps-script

I use this script to create a file, a folder and then insert that file in that folder and get ID:

```
var filedb = SpreadsheetApp.create("FileDBValueYourTime")     
var folder = DriveApp.createFolder("ValueYourTime")
  var idfolder = folder.getId()
  var idfile = filedb.getId()
  var movefile = DriveApp.getFileById(idfile)
  folder.addFile(movefile)
  //save ID file and folder
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperty('FILEID', idfile)
   scriptProperties.setProperty('FOLDERID', idfolder)
```

So when I use this script in a default GCP run it, but now I have to convert it in a Standard GCP and it doesn't run. Why? Have you suggests?

> Code of error: Exception: Sorry. A server error has occurred. Please
>   wait and try again.

what it could be?

Comment: I could not reproduce this behaviour. I switched to a standard GCP project and got it to work successfully. Are you sure you followed [the steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project) to switch to a standard project completely, including setting the OAuth consent screen with the appropriate scopes? In any case, since what you got is a server error, it might be a temporary problem on the server side. I'd suggest you to wait a bit and try again.

Comment: I start receiving similar issue this morning `Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.` when I used DriveApp.createFolder or DriveApp.getRootFolder. I don't know what is going on with Google Servers

Comment: Try enabling Drive api in Resources> Advanced Google services

Comment: Thanks at All! Solution is in OAuth: Authorize write and read file created with this app in Google Drive. Thanks Thanks Thanks! Now I've got another  problem: how to post it correctly here this solution?

Comment: Glad your issue was solved. I'd suggest you to post an answer explaining what was the problem and how you solved it: it can be useful for other people. To do that, write your answer in the text area below comments and click the button `Post Your Answer`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this script to create a file, a folder and then insert that file in that folder and get ID:

```
var filedb = SpreadsheetApp.create("FileDBValueYourTime")     
var folder = DriveApp.createFolder("ValueYourTime")
  var idfolder = folder.getId()
  var idfile = filedb.getId()
  var movefile = DriveApp.getFileById(idfile)
  folder.addFile(movefile)
  //save ID file and folder
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperty('FILEID', idfile)
   scriptProperties.setProperty('FOLDERID', idfolder)
```

So when I use this script in a default GCP run it, but now I have to convert it in a Standard GCP and it doesn't run.

Solution is in OAuth: Authorize write and read file created with this app in Google Drive.